# Iframe not resizing IE10

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-10

I found this bit of popular javascript doesn't work in IE10. I didn't create it but am maintaining a site that implements this. Was wondering if anyone else came across it. It seems the Document.getElemsntById('frame').onload event isn't working but the window.resize event does. Meaning on initial frame load it doesn't re-size but when I do anything to the window it does. Its just a pdf opening in an Iframe. Seems fine in all browsers except IE10 , on both Win 7 and 8 machines.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe() {
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    height -= document.getElementById('frame').offsetTop;
    height -= 250;         
    document.getElementById('frame').style.height = height +"px"; 
    };
    document.getElementById('frame').onload = resizeIframe;
    window.onresize = resizeIframe;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I was too vague in the question. I did Google this and found similar situations but not exactly like mine. I alerted out the height var and checked with a conditional and like I mentioned the browser would only run the function on resize, all other browsers were fine. I don't know why but I decided to add empty parenthesis to the call in on the onload event and it worked.

```
document.getElementById('frame').onload = resizeIframe();
```